# index management on Magento2, update by schedule, not working...?

Tags: magento2, stock, indexing

My setting for index management is currently update by schedule, as somehow Update on save seems to be not working.

I have saved a configurable product with correct stock setting, however, it appears as out of stock. And the last stock index apppears as Jan 19, 2017, 2:39:05 PM (now is Jan 21, 2017, 8:43 AM).

Is something wrong with my setting??
My magento is ver. 2.1.3.

My cron settings are as follows.

```
/usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /magento/var/log/magento.cron.log

/usr/local/bin/php /magento/update/cron.php >> /magento/var/log/update.cron.log

/usr/local/bin/php /magento/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /magento/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Comment: Have setup cron for this.

Comment: yes, I have my cron set up. I updated my question above.

Comment: Did you check error log if there any things.

Comment: I don't see any errors. Is it supposed to be so? Or every minute or hour etc updated??

Comment: it was nothing to do with the cron issue. When I create configurable product, it was set as out of stock even though I set the quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was nothing to do with the cron. 
When I create configurable product, it was set as out of stock even though I set the quantity.

Comment: Have you set the qty and manage stock of associated product with that main configurable product.

Comment: Yes I did set the quantity

Comment: can show using screen-sort what you setup in configurable and simple associated product.

Comment: I just needed to give some quantity in the parent "configurable" product, save, then the simple product with the quantity was properly saved as "in stock".